# I don't understand how how this code works

Tags: c, while-loop, char, whitespace, getchar

I'm doing Exercise 1-9 in the K&R Book, while trying to find solutions I came across this code:

```
int main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            while ((c = getchar()) == ' ');
            putchar(' ');
            if (c == EOF) break;
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

Why does the first `if` statement work if even if I input a letter. From my understanding it will only execute if the character I input is a blank space?
Btw the exercise is making a program replace multiple consecutive blank spaces to a single one.

Comment: Nowadays, I think it's more common to write `while ((c = getchar()) == ' ') { }` instead of `... ;`, to make it obvious that the loop has no body and only executes the side-effects of its condition.

Comment: What do you mean with "the first if statement work"? I mean: what do you understand by "work". The statement, specifically it's condition will always be evaluated in the outer while loop.

Comment: "Why does the first if statement work if even if I input a letter." What do you mean by "work"? What exactly do you think should happen? What exactly do you think is happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clarifying K&R exercise 1-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952514/clarifying-kr-exercise-1-9)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel What I think how it works is first, it takes a user input and then if my input contains multiple spaces it will replace them to a single one. Why would ```if (c == ' ')``` work if my input has a letter? I thought that c is equal to my input. If I input abc  d, why does the if statement still get executed? Doesn't it only works if I input only a single space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've formatted out and comented the code. Hope that'll help. The code actually covert all
sequence of spaces within `stdin` into one space:

```
 "123    456 a  b c  " -> "123 456 a b c "
```

Code:

```c
int main() {
    int c;
 
    /* we read stdin character after character */
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        /* if we have read space */   
        if (c == ' ') {
            /* we skip ALL spaces */
            while ((c = getchar()) == ' ')
                ; /* skipping ALL spaces: we do nothing */

            /* and then we print just ONE space instead of many skipped */
            putchar(' ');

            /* if we at the end of stdin, we have nothing more to print */
            if (c == EOF) 
                break;
        }

        /* we print every non space character */
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to clarify, does getchar() reads one letter or number at a time?

Comment: @airismything: `getchar()` reads a **byte** from the standard input stream (the terminal or some other source). A *byte* is a single character typed or in case of a non-ASCII character a single byte of its representation. If you type a number, each digit will be returned in sequence.

Answer (score 4):

This program prints any entered character except the blank character ' ' until the user will interrupt the input.

In this while loop

```
while ((c = getchar()) == ' ');
```

each blank character is read but not outputted. And after the loop only one blank character is outputted

```
putchar(' ');
```

That is the program removes adjacent blank characters leaving only one blank character in the input sequence of characters entered by the user.

Answer (score 0):

It loops as long as the input stream doesn't end (EOF = End Of File).

If the entered character is a space, it will ignore any follow-up spaces and only print one space afterwards.

Otherwise it will output the entered character.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
```

For each character of input...

```
        if (c == ' ') {
```

...if the character is a space...

```
            while ((c = getchar()) == ' ');
```

... this loop skips all spaces that come after the first...  See the semicolon in the right, that makes it read the character, check that it is a space, and **does nothing with it.**  It is a very tricky thing to write it as such, as it is quite common to think that the loop body will be the next statement below, while it has no body at all.  After a `while` loop, you can assume that the condition that let you enter the loop is false, so we have some true assertion: in `c` there's for sure no space stored (it can still be `EOF`, which is not a character, so we need to test for it before printing, and we do it next, after the next statement)

```
            putchar(' ');
```

... after the loop, only a single space is output, corresponding to the one tested in the first `if` statement you mentioned in your question.  Think that `c` is not a space character (so we cannot `putchar(c);`), as we skip all spaces until none remained.  Still it can be an `EOF` indicator, that is checked below.

```
            if (c == EOF) break;
```

if the character was not a space, it could only be an `EOF` indicator.  In that case, we need to get out of the loop so we don't print it, in the next statement...

```
        }
        putchar(c);
```

... as we have been reading characters in `c` until we got a non space (nor an `EOF` indicator, as we got out of the loop above in that case) we need to print that char anyway.  This `putchar(c);` statement will always print a non-space character.  It is out of the `if` statement, as it must be done for all the characters that were initially nonspaces and the characters that followed a sequence of spaces.

```
    }
```

...As above, we can assume the test condition of the loop is false, so here we can ensure that `c` has got `EOF` (but only because the  `break` statement inside the loop also happens when `c == EOF`).

```
}
```

Et voila!!!

#### Note

> while *trying to find solutions I came across this code:*

A final note, it is better for you if you post your attempt at programming a solution, instead of finding already made solutions by searching.  You'll learn more on programming and less on googling, which IMHO is not your primary interest.